# Is it possible to instantiate child class from a static method in base class [node JS]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, base-class

I want to create an instance of child class from a static method in a base class

```
class Base {
  static find(id) {
    const attributes = database.get(id);
    return new getChildClass(attributes);
  }
}

class FirstChild extends Base {
}

class SecondChild extends Base {
}
```

I want `FirstChild.find(1)` to return an instance of `FirstChild` and 
`SecondChild.find(1)` to return an instance of `SecondChild`

Is in possible to achieve this in node JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `find` from the child class, `this` inside `find` will refer to that child class, so you can just `return new this` from `find`:

```js
class Base {
  static find(id) {
    const attributes = 'foo'; // database.get(id);
    return new this(attributes);
  }
}

class FirstChild extends Base {
}

class SecondChild extends Base {
}

console.log(FirstChild.find(1) instanceof FirstChild);
console.log(SecondChild.find(1) instanceof SecondChild);
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve the same thing in typescript without it resulting in an error?

Comment: @Jammer It looks to work fine in TS as-is, if you just add the type annotations when necessary